# NSPredicate Filter Children Objects Return Parent

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter the following example of an JSON object in an NSArray form.

```
[
   {
       "Name": "Andrew",
       "Age": 28,
       "Pets": [
          {
              "Name": "Domino"
          },
          {
              "Name": "Sheldon"
          }
       ]
   },
   {
       "Name": "Matthew",
       "Age": 26,
       "Pets": [
          {
              "Name": "Shadow"
          },
          {
              "Name": "Mojo"
          }
       ]
   }
]
```

I want to filter where `Pets.Name` contains string `"Sha"`

Given this predicate I'd want the result matches to be:

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Matthew",
      "Age":26,
      "Pets":[
         {
            "Name":"Shadow"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What is an easy way to do this?

```
 NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Pets.Name == %@", searchText];
 NSArray *temp = [MY_ARRAY filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ANY SQL command like so:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY Pets.Name == %@", searchText];
```